# Power BI and Role Based Security for 800 people

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created a role in Power BI desktop - filters the data using `UserPrincipalName()`.

I go to Security in the Power BI Service and add a member to the role. Everything works great!

Now, I need to add another 799 members to this role. Isn't there an easier way? How do I make this work so that for any user that runs the report, the filter kicks in and the user sees all data related to them, without explicitly adding them to the role I defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
User = CONCATENATEX(Responses, IF(Responses[Feedback For] = USERPRINCIPALNAME(), "This User", "Other User"))
```

I created a measure called **User** and added this measure as a filter - locked it and made it invisible.

[image: User Filter]